# how to stop placeholder from floating as label in angular 8 mat select

Tags: angular-material, angular7, angular8

I have a matselect field , I dont want the placeholder to float as label , I want to use it only as placeholder, I tried giving floatPlaceholder = "never" also tried as label and given floatLabel = "never" , but still it floating. Need suggestions

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Function" floatPlaceholder="never">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of functionOptions" 
  [value]="option.name">    
       {{option.name}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: `<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3mgna Check this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-placeholder).

you can play with open/close events and change placeholder value manually.